# Use dict to replace word in string

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7

Im trying to replace one part of my string using a dict.

```
s  = 'I am a string replaceme'

d = {
'replaceme':  'replace me'
 }
```

Ive tried lots of variations like

```
s = s.replace(d, d[other])
```

That throws an error being *name error: name 'other' is not defined*. If I do

```
s = s.replace('replaceme', 'replace me')
```

It works. How can i achive my goal?

Comment: `for frm, to_ in d.items(): s = s.replace(frm, to_)` (but note you may have issues with order). Why not use actual string formatting, e.g. with `%` or `{}`?

Comment: why are you doing this?

Comment: I have made a program that uses pyttsx to read out text. Im using this to make abrivations say whole words.  Pyttsx has no support for this. So home grown I go

Comment: How big are the text and dictionary? What you are doing is going to be incredibly inefficient for large amounts of data

Comment: 4 - 6 letter long and changed 1 - 6 times depending on string.

Comment: Inefficiency isn't an issue it wont be used too often

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace each KEY of your dict with the VALUE associated. Which value holds the `other` variable? Is it a valid KEY of your substitutions dict?
You can try with this solution.

```
for k in d:
    s = s.replace(k, d[k])
```

Each key in dictionary is the value to be replaced, using the corresponding VALUE accessed with `d[k]`.
If the dictionary is big the provided example will show poor performances.

Comment: `... in d` iterates only over keys, this will be a `ValueError`

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and rejoin:

```
s = 'I am a string replaceme'

d = {
'replaceme':  'replace me'
 }

print(" ".join([w if w not in d else d[w] for w in s.split(" ")]))
```

That won't match substrings where `str.replace` will, if you are trying to match substring iterate over the `dict.items` and replace the key with the value:

```
d = {
'replaceme':  'replace me'
 }

for k,v in d.items():
    s = s.replace(k,v)

print(s)

I am a string replace me
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach: using `reduce`:

```
s  = 'I am a string replaceme'
d = {'replaceme': 'replace me', 'string': 'phrase,'}
s = reduce(lambda text, old_new_pair: text.replace(* old_new_pair), d.items(), s)
# s is now 'I am a phrase, replace me'
```